# How to force delete an SSH identity from ssh-agent when `ssh-add -D` fails. (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-agent

I have erroneously loaded an ssh key in the ssh-agent. I tried running `ssh-add -D` as I had no other important identities on this agent but this command deleted all identities except the one I was trying to delete.

When trying to delete this last identity it would fail with the message `Failed to remove all identities.`

I also tried to restart the machine and kill the ssh-agent via task manager, but `ssh-add.exe -v -l` would keep listing the key I am trying to delete.

How can I force the ssh-agent to forget all keys?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the help of ChatGPT.

Apparently running `ssh-agent -k` forces the agent to clear its in-memory store.

It is unclear to me why killing the process and restarting the machine failed to do so.

this would have been easier is `ssh-agent -h` printed any info.